# How to make CountVectorizer not segment features names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, countvectorizer

I have a column in a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Receiver_email_root": ["idatta.91", "datta.indrajeet", "indiejesse.d", "idatta.91"]})
```

After applying CountVectorizer on that column and then printing out the feature names, I get the feature names to be like this:

```
Receiver_email_root feature names:  ['91', 'datta',  'idatta', 'indiejesse', 'indrajeet', 'd']
```

But I want the feature names for CountVectorizer to consider to be like this:

`Receiver_email_root_feature_names : ['idatta.91', 'datta.indrajeet', 'indiejesse.d']`

as they are in the column without getting segmented at delimitters such as '.'

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The [`CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) provided by `scikit-learn` features a `token_pattern` parameter which, i.a., states:

> The default regexp select tokens of 2 or more alphanumeric characters (punctuation is completely ignored and always treated as a token separator).

You can change this behavior by specifying your own regexp:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer


count_vect = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r'\w+\.\w+')

df = pd.DataFrame({"Receiver_email_root": ["idatta.91", "datta.indrajeet", "indiejesse.d", "idatta.91"]})
vector = pd.DataFrame(count_vect.fit_transform(df["Receiver_email_root"]).toarray())
vector.columns = count_vect.get_feature_names()
```

When you check `vector.columns.values` you will get

```
['datta.indrajeet' 'idatta.91' 'indiejesse.d']
```

You have to be careful with this though as now the `CountVectorizer` will only consider tokens of this particular pattern.